# Timestamp abbreviated date format natively in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm converting successfully to timestamps numerical formats of dates (y-m-d, yyyyMMdd, etc) in spark using `sql.functions.unix_timestamp`.

The problem is when the date uses an abbreviated name of a month or a day, like 
`1991-Aug-09 Fri`

Is there any way to achieve the conversion using only native spark functions?

(**Disclaimer:** I know I can do it using python functions, it's just curiosity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ([reference - SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html))

```
yyyy-MMM-dd EEE
```

format with `unix_timestamp`

```
spark.sql("SELECT CAST(unix_timestamp('1991-Aug-09 Fri', 'yyyy-MMM-dd EEE') AS TIMESTAMP)").show()
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|CAST(unix_timestamp(1991-Aug-09 Fri, yyyy-MMM-dd EEE) AS TIMESTAMP)|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                1991-08-09 00:00:00|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

or `to_date` / `to_timestamp` (Spark 2.2 or later):

```
spark.sql("SELECT to_date('1991-Aug-09 Fri', 'yyyy-MMM-dd EEE')").show()
+--------------------------------------------+
|to_date('1991-Aug-09 Fri', 'yyyy-MMM-dd EEE'|
+--------------------------------------------+
|                                  1991-08-09|
+--------------------------------------------+
```